# Avoid people navigating away from VB user form

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is it possible to stop people from navigating away from a user form in Visual Basic using ALT-TAB, WINKEY and CTRL-ALT-DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some arcane way of doing it with Win API calls, trapping and handling Windows messages yourself, but with pure VB/VBA?  No.